# How does mongoid know to use plural name of a model when using references?

Tags: mongoid

I was reading this [mongoid link](http://one.mongoid.org/docs/relations/referenced/1-1.html), and it came up with this:

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :posts
end

class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title, type: String
  belongs_to :person
end
```

How does mongoid know that `has_many :posts` refers to the `Post` class? Would it be the same if it was `has_many :post`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it shows in the [current Mongoid documentation](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html#storage), Mongoid uses `ActiveSupport::Inflector` to translate between singular and plural model and table names.